# Opencv VideoCapture with multithread

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I am trying to display multi-videos by using multithread with cv::VideoCapture and std::thread. If I just call function work(), it works! But when I put it into a thread, nothing is displayed. Did I miss anything here? Or do you have a better parctice to do so? Thanks!

p.s. I'm using Mac OS X 10.10.2, Opencv 2.4.9

Here is the code:

```
void work(std::string address, std::string window) {
    cv::VideoCapture cap(address);
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cout << "Cannot open camera" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    cv::Mat frame;
    while (char(cv::waitKey(1)) != 'q' && cap.isOpened()) {
        cap >> frame;
        if(frame.empty()) {
            std::cout << "Video over" << std::endl;
            break; 
        }
        cv::imshow(window, frame);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::thread t1(work, "/Path/to/test.mp4", "test");
    t1.join();

    // work("/Path/to/test.mp4", "test"); // it works if just call function work()

    std::cout << "Done..." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on Windows 7; do you by chance have a line `cv::namedWindow("test");` in your actual code? If I include that in the main function before the thread is created, I just get a gray screen and the application hangs. If you do have, try moving the window function inside the `work` function so the window is created by the thread that is doing the displaying and checking for keyboard input.

Comment: It doesn't work, either. I found if I include cv::namedWindow() before the thread is created, it can just show me the first frame of the video and the application hangs. But I get a gray screen and the application hangs if I remove cv::namedWindow(). I am really confused.

Comment: Strange. As far as the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow) is concerned, `imshow` creates the window automatically, and so it should work if you don't initialize the window from the main function and try to access it from the thread. If you place `cv::nameWindow("test");` in the work function, does it also produce a gray screen and hang?

Comment: Hi. Any progress on question? I also have a problem when I try to create stereocam viewer on python. They run fine on multiple process, but not on multiple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cv::imshow() in an additional thread might not be a good idea. cv::imshow() only works well in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but you probably miss a `cv::waitKey(5);` after the call to `cv::imshow`.